# How to do the following matrix multiplication more efficient in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I was wondering if there is any way of doing the following matrix multiplication more efficient, as for example vectorizing it:

```
m=1000;n=500;
a=zeros(n,1);
b=rand(n,1);
A=rand(m,n);
B=rand(m,m);
for i=1:n
    a(i)=b'*(A'*B(i,:)'*B(i,:)*A)*b;
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the answers solve your problem, please consider marking as accepted one that suits your needs best:) (I believe the solution of Luis is not only simpler, but also faster and more memory-efficient.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can greatly reduce the number of operations using [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Matrix_product_.28any_number.29) and the [transpose-product property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Properties_of_the_matrix_product_.28two_matrices.29):

```
t = B*A*b;
a = abs(t).^2;
```

This works because the original expression `b'*(A'*B(i,:)'*B(i,:)*A)*b` equals `b'*A'*B(i,:)'*B(i,:)*A*b` (by associativity), which equals `(B(i,:)*a*b)'*B(i,:)*A*b` (by the transpose-product property); and the latter can be computed for all `i` as `(B*a*b)'*B*A*b`.

If your matrices contain real numbers, you can perhaps gain some speed removing `abs`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Thanks! I believe this will be faster than your approach. I always try to avoid computing a matrix just to keep the diagonal only :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will:) Not to mention memory-efficient.

Comment: Yes, it actually is much more efficient

Answer (score 5):

I suggest reordering the matrix multiplications to have `B` and `B'` on the sides, and using `diag` to get the diagonal elements:

```
m=1000;n=500;
a=zeros(n,1);
b=rand(n,1);
A=rand(m,n);
B=rand(m,m);

%original for comparison
for i=1:n
    a(i)=b'*(A'*B(i,:)'*B(i,:)*A)*b;
end

%new version
%a2=diag(B*A*b*b'*A'*B');
%a2=a2(1:n); %emulate original cut-off

%new new version
a2=diag(B(1:n,:)*A*b*b'*A'*B(1:n,:)');

%compare difference
max(abs(a-a2)) %absolute error
max(abs(a-a2))./max(abs(a)) %relative error
```

The absolute error seems large compared to `rand()`:

```
>> max(abs(a-a2)) %absolute error

ans =

   8.1062e-06
```

but the relative error shows that we are correct to machine precision:

```
>> max(abs(a-a2))./max(abs(a)) %relative error

ans =

   1.9627e-15
```

---

The maths behind the rearranging is that a single term in your original sum,

```
b'*(A'*B(i,:)'*B(i,:)*A)*b
```

is a series of matrix products, if you think of vectors as row/column matrices. And since the first and last dimensions (through `b'` and `b`) are both 1, you get a scalar result for each `i`. If you think of this scalar as a `1 x 1` matrix, you can substitute it with its own trace. And, matrices can be cyclically permuted under a trace:

```
Tr (b' * A * Bi' * Bi * A * b) = Tr (Bi * A * b * b' * A * Bi')
```

where for simplicity `Bi` stands for the `i`th row of `B`. But what we have right now inside the trace is *again* a scalar, so we can remove the trace. So for each `i` you need

```
a(i)=B(i,:) * A * b * b' * A * B(i,:)';
```

which is clearly the `(i,i)` (diagonal) component of the matrix

```
B * A * b * b' * A * B'
```

Comment: Awesome! Works great!
Thank you